# Firebase not loading the data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue?
Firebase's started not loading the data on deployed and virtual devices all of a sudden

Tryed out to clone the code and implement with the new database on another Google profile, but it doesn't help so far.

Deployed on:

- Apple AppStore (TestFlight)
- Google Play Market

[image]

Vedeo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/61sDV.jpg

Comment: working fine in debug more ?

Comment: Same issue :(
paste.ofcode.org/U8CHjHMRNa9Z8zqedC6CKg

Comment: show me the code

Comment: Yeah mate, sorry for that. Are you comfortable to share your email by any chance I'll be adding you straight to the project if you're comfortable with? :)

Comment: awaisdev5765@gmail.com

Comment: So much mate. Just added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the issue was caused by config files on Firebase somehow those configs are affected the entire database and deleting them and reconfiguring has helped to resolve it.

To be more precise I went to `Project settings` -> `Your apps` -> `SDK setup and configuration` section then added the new config files for each Android, iOS, Web apps. And voila the app is back on :)